# How to Keep colors on gridview after Postback? asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, postback

I have a gridview which I change some of the rows colors after using RowDataBound....

Here's my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdvEventosVendedor" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DatakeyNames="idCita"
                EmptyDataText="No Hay Eventos Para Este Vendedor" ForeColor="#333333" 
                GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True"
                onpageindexchanging="grdvEventosVendedor_PageIndexChanging" 
                onrowcommand="grdvEventosVendedor_RowCommand" 
                onsorting="grdvEventosVendedor_Sorting" CellSpacing="1" 
                onrowdatabound="grdvEventosVendedor_RowDataBound" >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775"/>

                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="35px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnEdicEvento" runat="server" 
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("idCita")%>' CommandName="Edicion" 
                                Height="32px" ImageUrl="~/img/pencil_32.png" Width="32px" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="35px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDelete" runat="server"
                                CommandName="Borrar" 
                                ImageUrl="~/img/1385_Disable_16x16_72.png" 
                                onclientclick="return confirm('¿Desea eliminar el registro?');" 
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("idCita")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Cliente" HeaderText="Cliente" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Cliente" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Empresa" HeaderText="Empresa" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Empresa" ItemStyle-Width="50px"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Telefono" HeaderText="Telefono" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Telefono" ItemStyle-Width="50px"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Nextel" HeaderText="Nextel" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Nextel" ItemStyle-Width="50px"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Tipo" HeaderText="Tipo" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Tipo" ItemStyle-Width="50px"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Descripcion" HeaderText="Descripcion" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Descripcion" ItemStyle-Width="150px"/>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fecha" SortExpression="Fecha" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFecha" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Fecha", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>'>
                            </asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <EditItemTemplate>                                        
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxFecha"  runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Fecha","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' ValidationGroup="gpEdicionAgenda">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="HoraInicio" HeaderText="Hora" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="HoraInicio" ItemStyle-Width="50px"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Lugar" HeaderText="Lugar" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Lugar" ItemStyle-Width="50px"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Estado" HeaderText="Estado" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Estado" ItemStyle-Width="50px"/>

                    <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Estado" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="dpdListEstado" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dpdListEstado_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" CommandArgument="">
                                <asp:ListItem>Pendiente</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Atendido</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>--%>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Atender" ItemStyle-Width="35px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnAtender" runat="server"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("idCita")%>' CommandName="Atender" 
                                ImageUrl="~/img/activar.png" Width="16px" Height="16px" 
                                onclientclick="return confirm('¿Desea marcar como atendido este registro?');" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CRM" ItemStyle-Width="35px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnCRM" runat="server"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IdCliente")%>' CommandName="CRM" 
                                ImageUrl="~/img/go.gif" Width="16px" Height="16px" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VM" ItemStyle-Width="35px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnVerMas" runat="server"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IdCliente")%>' CommandName="VerMas" 
                                ImageUrl="~/img/search.png" Width="16px" Height="16px" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>

                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" Font-Size="Small" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Larger" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Size="Small" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

in my cs I have...

```
    private static string strColorUrgente = "#FF525D";
    private static string strColorEnCurso = "#FFDE00";
    private static string strColorHoy = "#3ECF00";
```

and here's the rowbounddata function

```
protected void grdvEventosVendedor_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex >= 0 && e.Row.Cells[11].Text == "Pendiente")
        {
            string strFecha = (e.Row.FindControl("lblFecha") as Label).Text;
            int intYear = Convert.ToInt32(strFecha.Split('/')[2]);
            int intMonth = Convert.ToInt32(strFecha.Split('/')[1]);
            int intDay = Convert.ToInt32(strFecha.Split('/')[0]);
            DateTime dtmFecha = new DateTime(intYear, intMonth, intDay);

            if (dtmFecha < DateTime.Today)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName(strColorUrgente);
            }

            else if (dtmFecha == DateTime.Today)
            {
                DateTime dtmHoraInicio = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[9].Text);

                if (dtmHoraInicio > DateTime.Now)
                {
                    e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName(strColorHoy);
                }

                else
                {
                    e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName(strColorEnCurso);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Whenever I enter to this page or I use a search engine, I refresh the gridview with a datasource, and of course, the RowDataBound is triggered... and eventually some of the rows' colors will be changed...

You'll notice that in the gridview, on the last column there's a button called imgBtnVerMas...

When pressed, it triggers the following function

```
string strMensaje = "";

        try
        {
            //Method that brings back data from a specific client (returns a datatable)
            //intIdCliente was defined in the CommandArgument
            DataTable dtDatosCliente = ConexionBD.GetInstanciaConexionBD().GetClienteEspecifico2(intIdCliente);
            //Assigning to a string a message that needs info from the previous datatable
            strMensaje += "DATOS DEL CLIENTE\\n\\nNombre:\\t" + dtDatosCliente.Rows[0]["Cliente"] + "\\nEmpresa: " + dtDatosCliente.Rows[0]["Empresa"];
        }

        catch
        {
            if (strMensaje == "")
            {
                strMensaje = "Hubo Un Error Al Traer Los Datos Del Cliente";
            }

            else
            {
                strMensaje += "\n\nERROR!!!!!!!";
            }
        }

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Mensaje", "alert('" + strMensaje + "');", true);
```

Afterwards, the message is displayed, however, all of the rows colors dissapear... I was wondering... how can I keep the colors of the gridview's rows even after a postback...

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set your colors on the event of `onprerender` and not on RowDataBound, so set the event on GridView

```
onprerender="gvMyLista_PreRender"
```

and on code behind

```
protected void gvMyLista_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // loop your data, and fix your colors.
   for (int i = 0; i < gvMyLista.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       // get your data as...
      // gvMyLista.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text
   }
}
```