# ASP.NET GridView is there a way to get column name based on the cell you are in

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
         {
             // .... here ....
             cell.Text = cell.Text.Replace(entry.Value, "<span class='highlightSearchTerm'>" + entry.Value + "</span>");
         }
     }

}
```

The part where it says .... here .... I need to somehow get the column name of the DataGrid. So based on which cell I am CURRENTLY in I need to get a Column name. Later in the code depending which Column I am in I need to do different formatting for the cell. Also Column names are not know at run time they are generated on the fly so I need a generic method to get a Column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By column Name if you mean `HeaderText` then you can use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`, Use the index to get `HeaderText` like:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[i];
            string HeaderText  = yourGridView.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            cell.Text = cell.Text.Replace(entry.Value,
                "<span class='highlightSearchTerm'>" + entry.Value + "</span>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. The only thing I had to add is `code`i < e.Row.Cells.Count - 1`code` for some reason it was giving out of range.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string currentColName = GridView1.Columns[GridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name;
```

Comment: `GridView1.Columns[0].Name` is the name of the  1st column,
`GridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex`   is an int number that is equal to the *number of the column of the current cell (selected cell)*.
I did not test this code, but it should work, did it work ? (Edit: made my comment easier to read)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way you have the loop, and make something like:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < gvMyLista.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       // get your data as...
       // gvMyLista.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text
   }
```

that you can direct see the `cell` and the `row`. The `gvMyLista` is the id of your GridView.

Now, if you make the formating here it maybe change after the post back, because the data may not bind again, so I suggest to make the formating on PreRender, here is a similar q/a: [How to Keep colors on gridview after Postback? asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042725/how-to-keep-colors-on-gridview-after-postback-asp-net-c-sharp/12043486#12043486)

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a method for myself for JUST this purpose. Things like this should be built into the objects, so that we can easily get the information that we need. When it's not built in, we have to get it ourselves, unfortunately:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Makes the assumption that the TableCell is a bound DataControlField cell, and returns the name of the column of the table
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tc"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string GetColumnNameOfTableCell (TableCell tc)
    {
        return ((BoundField)((DataControlFieldCell)tc).ContainingField).DataField;
    }
```